# How to get a value from inside an href in the HTML structure

Tags: python, scrapy

I am using the following code to get values from a site

```
import scrapy

class scraping(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'NewsSpider'
    start_urls = ['https://www.uol.com.br/']

    def parse(self, response):
        news = response.xpath('//article')
        for n in news:
            print({
                'Link': n.xpath("//a[@class='hyperlink headlineSub__link']").get(),
                'Title': n.xpath('//a/div/h3/text()').get(),
            })
```

On "Link" I am getting a lot of information but I want to get only the link inside the href, is it possible to get only that information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a sample of doing this very same thing. You should use something like this selector:

```
.css('a[href*=topic]::attr(href)')
```

`a tag` in my case was something like `<a ... href="topic/1321343">something</a>`.
**The key is `a::attr(href)`**
parse your response and make it as small as you can and get your wanted href value.

[This](https://github.com/mhbahmani/Microsoft-Academic-Crawling/blob/master/mir/mir/spiders/spiders.py#L57) is my solution on a project for scraping [Microsoft Academia](https://academic.microsoft.com/paper/2743138268/reference/search?q=Anomaly%20Detection%20with%20Robust%20Deep%20Autoencoders&qe=Or(Id%253D2919115771%252CId%253D2101234009%252CId%253D2296319761%252CId%253D2557283755%252CId%253D2164278908%252CId%253D2112796928%252CId%253D2271840356%252CId%253D2025768430%252CId%253D2145094598%252CId%253D1498436455%252CId%253D2384495648%252CId%253D2050834445%252CId%253D2296719434%252CId%253D2146337213%252CId%253D2218318129%252CId%253D2001818158%252CId%253D2039632702%252CId%253D1886579186%252CId%253D2418020448%252CId%253D1536329667%252CId%253D2966356637%252CId%253D1617415790)&f=&orderBy=0) articles. The linked line gets items in "Related Topics" section.

Here is some other example:

```
<span class="title">
  <a href="https://www.example.com"></a>
</span>
```

pars by:

```
Link = Link1.css('span.title a::attr(href)').extract()[0]
```